# Regex - matching numbers between hyphens

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to piece together a regex to match a number between hyphens.

general

```
a-b-c-d-e, where a,b,c,d,e can each be either one, two or three digit numbers.
```

example

```
9-b-90-2-2    

19-b-390-2-2
```

How can I select the number b from each expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the below regex to get only the number b,

```
^[^-]*-([^-]*).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/43)

```
>>> str = "9-b-90-2-2 "
>>> m = re.findall(r'^[^-]*-([^-]*).*', str)
>>> m 
['b']
```

If the input contains one or more lines then you need to enable MULTILINE modifier,

```
>>> str = """9-45-90-2-2 
... 9-45-90-2-2-89-878"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^[^-]*-([^-]*).*', str, re.MULTILINE)
>>> m
['45', '45']
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it without regex

```
num = "9-b-90-2-2"
print num.split('-')[1] # b
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex for this, but the regex is straightforward:

```
(?<=-)(\d+)
```

[Demo at Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gS3yF2/2)

Basically, this just matches the digits following the first hyphen.